# elastic4s query search function score

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

how I can create the query with client elastic4s scala?

I call using marvel/sense

```
GET /business/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "my text"
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_score  +  log(doc['reviews'].value + 1 )",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "industry": {
      "terms": {
        "fields": ["type", "industry"]

      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

But how I can create the query with elastic4s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a function score query like this:

```
val req = search in "marvel/sense" query {
 functionScoreQuery(matchQuery("name", "my_text")).scorers(
  scriptScore("_score  +  log(doc['reviews'].value + 1 )")
 )
}
```

Then of course add in the facets, etc following the instructions at https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/guide/search.md

Comment: what if I wanted to add filters, also ?